# Referencing objects which don't exist yet

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am teaching myself Python by reinventing the wheel, i.e. writing a simple console adventure game with interconnected rooms. My interest is not so much in finishing a real game, rather in learning about abstraction and data structures.

I have defined a few basic classes such as `World`, which contains references to `Rooms`. These Rooms have Actions and Items. The program checks which Actions are available for each Room and displays them in a list. All of this is working pretty well so I'm trying to *complexify* things a bit.

> I have two problems I can't get my head around. I'll try to explain
>   them with as little detail as possible.

This is how I defined a possible Action for a `Room`, in this instance it's a `Room` referenced by the variable called `main` (for now data is declared in a module, later to be read from a `CSV` or `XML` file):

```
main.actions = [Action(type = 'move',
                       result = 'west',
                       desc = 'Go to the West Room.')]
```

I need to define an action type because some actions are not movements (e.g. pick up, pull a lever). I'll modify this later to uses subclasses of Action, it's not the issue here.

The 'west' string here refers to the Room which will be the result of the action, i.e. it will become the current room when the action is executed.

> However, I'd like the result to be the *Room object* itself, not a
>   *string ID*. But I can't do that until all the `Rooms` have been initialized.

So I've solved this with the following method of the World object, which works:

```
    def connect_rooms(self):
    '''
    Once all the rooms have been created,
    replace all the string reference to other rooms by the Room objects themselves.
    '''
    for room in self.rooms:
        for action in room.actions:
            if action.type == 'move':
                room_object = fetch_room(self, action.result)
                action.result = room_object
```

The `fetch_room()` function (global scope) just does this:

```
def fetch_room(world, shortname):
# Find a room item by its shortname
for room in world.rooms:
    if room.shortname == shortname:
        return room
return None
```

I am sure there is a better way to handle this, since creating connections between nodes seems to be a basic abstract idea.

**The other (related) problem** is that I'm trying to create conditions built into the Actions themselves, so that the program only proposes them to the player if the conditions *defined in the Action* are met. For the initial building of the data I can't reference anything else because it hasn't been created yet. I thought of adding a condition in string form and run it later with exec(), but it seems very silly and ugly:

```
main.actions = [Action(type = 'move',
                   result = 'west',
                   desc = 'Go to the West Room.',
                   conditions = ["player.has('smallkey')"])]
```

If there is a text somewhere about build such data structures without going insane, I'd be happy to read it.

Thank you.

Comment: Well done, you are doing great! What's your question?

Comment: What stops you from initializing rooms before you configure actions?

Comment: I agree with Elmo - just initialize all of your stuff first if you need it to exist. As for the conditions, could you use a lambda and arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've learned a lot since this morning. Even managed to make keys from one room open a door in another. This is the future! My questions were clear, I thought. Thanks for highlighting them. If I initialize the Rooms before I configure Actions, I need to keep each and every room in a separate variable so I can reference it later (that's why I wrote the fetch_room function). Right now the world setup looks just like a bunch of assignments and I'd like to be able to streamline in by reading a text file. Is my idea of substituting a string name for the Room object OK?